# Spring MockMvcResultMatchers jsonPath lower/greater than

Tags: java, spring, mockmvc

I'm using MockMvcResultMatchers to test my controller classes.

Here is a sample code

```
        RequestBuilder request = get("/employee/")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);

        mockMvc
            .perform(request)
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.total").exists());
```

But how i can compare $.total value with number?

I mean, is there a way to find out that $.total > 0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

json path `value` method can take `org.hamcrest.Matcher` as parameter. So you can use `GreaterThan` class:

```
jsonPath("['key']").value(new GreaterThan(1))
```

This class is from `org.mockito.internal.matchers` package.

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Comment: Where is `jsonPath` located?

Comment: @zygimantus this may help you: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/integration-testing-of-spring-mvc-applications-write-clean-assertions-with-jsonpath/

Comment: Can I use this matcher to check the size of an array from the jsonPath?

Comment: Just discovered that to check the size of an array you have to add **.length()** to the **jsonPath**, but then I get
`java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.result.length()" expected:<gt(0)> but was:<3>`

Comment: What worked for me was:
`.andExpect(jsonPath("$.result.length()", greaterThan(0)));`

Comment: With `org.hamcrest.Matchers.greaterThan` you can do `jsonPath("$.result.length()", greaterThan(0))`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [greaterThan()](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#greaterThan(T)) method with hasSize().

As an example, you should do like below:

```java
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.result", hasSize(greaterThan(0))))
```

You can check it out other methods of `org.hamcrest.Matchers` class from [here](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html).